# Authenticating JWT Vertx

Tags: authentication, jwt, vert.x

I have successfully generated a JWT token using RSA Keys from the documentation, I want to secure the endpoints and authenticate JWT, that's where I got stuck. Here is what I have done

AuthConfig

```
        JWTAuthOptions options = new JWTAuthOptions()
                // add public key
                .addPubSecKey(new PubSecKeyOptions()
                        .setAlgorithm(algorithm)
                        .setBuffer("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                                publicKey String
                                "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"))
                // add private key
                .addPubSecKey(new PubSecKeyOptions()
                        .setAlgorithm(algorithm)
                        .setBuffer("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
                                privatekey String
                                "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"));

        return JWTAuth.create(vertx, options);
    }
```

JWTBuilder

```
 public JwtBuilderHandlerImpl(JWTAuth jwtAuth) {
        this.jwtAuth = jwtAuth;
    }

public String buildToken(String subject) {
       return jwtAuth.generateToken(new JsonObject()
                       .put("message", "token-data"),
               new JWTOptions()
                       .setHeader(new JsonObject().put("Bearer", "Bearer"))
                       .setSubject(subject)
                       .setIssuer(issuer)
                       .setAlgorithm(algorithm)
                       .setExpiresInMinutes(2840));

    }
```

The build token method is called from the controller to generate the JWT token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need and endpoint that will exchange generate JWT (call your controller) so that the user can obtain it. Also you will need to protect all other resources so that they can be only accessed with valid JWT generated from your app.

Here is simple example to protect all endpoints starting with /api/ so that they require valid JWT:

```
router.route("/api/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(jwt));
```

Also for more detailed example please check official example:
[vertx-jwt-example](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/4.x/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/jwt/Server.java)

Comment: This is helpful thank you so much. For clarification purposes, where are the details of the KeyStoreOptions like setType, setPath, and setPassword derived from?

Comment: These options are used when using java keystore file for storing/loading your keys. The options that you referenced are used to specify path of your keystore file, type (there are couple of options) and password if the keystore is password protected. I would strongly suggest to use this way to store and load keys in your app as storing them in source code is not a recommended way.

Comment: Thanks I will look into Java KeyStore and refactor accordingly

Comment: Hello, all endpoints are protected now, please can I get a sample code that implements the endpoint that will exchange generate JWT so that the user can obtain it?

Comment: In the example I have sent, there is a endpoint `/api/newToken` which sends the token back to user in response. What is missing there is for example to collect username and password from request, check in Database and if everything is ok send the token. This part is up to you to implement as you need, but skeleton is already there in the example.

Comment: Hi Pendula, I have successfully implemented the JWT Authentication and authorization for signing up, but for the project, I'm working on OTP verification as a preferred option for phone number verification and not email using JWT. I have looked at the Vert.x HOTP and TOTP authentication provider but not much is provided there. what library is best for Otp authentication and Authorization?